# Related rates of change - ship question

Tags: calculus

A ship is 5km east and 7km north of a lighthouse. It is moving north at a rate of 12km/h and east at a rate of 16km/h. At what rate is its distance from the lighthouse changing?

My working:

$\dfrac{dS_n}{dt}=12t+7$

$\dfrac{dS_e}{dt}=16t+5$

Because the displacement north is initially 7, and every t, it travels 12km N and so on for east.

Is this correct? Do I integrate both to obtain a displacement?

The answer is 19.1km/h

Comment: You need to drop the constants from your equations for the rates.  The constants don't contribute to the rate.

Comment: Or did you actually mean to write the equations for $S_n$ and $S_e$ rather than their derivatives? You need $S_n$ and $S_e$ for the solution (and you need their derivatives, but you can easily find those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$ S^2 = S_e^2 + S_n^2 \rightarrow $

$\displaystyle 2S\frac{dS}{dt} = 2S_e\frac{dS_e}{dt} + 2S_n\frac{dS_n}{dt} \rightarrow$

$\displaystyle \frac{dS}{dt} = \frac{S_e}{S}\frac{dS_E}{dt}+\frac{S_n}{S}\frac{dS_n}{dt}$

Now, if you think about it, you know everything on the right hand side.